# UIImage is nil after UIImagePickerController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

When the value of iImage is printed out it says: " **size {3024, 4032} orientation 3 scale 1.000000**", but then I get the error: "**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**" on the next line. How can the image I just got be nil?

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let iImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        print(iImage)
        createEvent(iImage)//where it is saved to cloudkit with location and title
        EventPageViewController().eventPic.image = iImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        let eventPageViewController:EventPageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventPage") as! EventPageViewController
        self.present(eventPageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func loadEvent(_ completion: @escaping (_ error:NSError?, _ records:[CKRecord]?) -> Void)
    {
        let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -60.0 * 180, since: NSDate() as Date)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", date)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Event", predicate: predicate)
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil){
            (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error fetching events: \(error)")
                completion(error as NSError?, nil)
            } else {
                print("found events")
                completion(nil, records)
                guard let records = records else {
                    return
                }
                for record in records
                {
                    self.drawEvents(record["LocationF"] as! CLLocation, title1: record["StringF"] as! String)

                    if let asset = record["Picture"] as? CKAsset,
                        let data = NSData(contentsOf: asset.fileURL),
                        let image1 = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                    {
                        //EventPageViewController().eventPic.image = image1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

func drawEvents(_ loc: CLLocation, title1: String)
    {
        mapView.delegate = self
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.coordinate.latitude, longitude: loc.coordinate.longitude)
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
        let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
        self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation1.title = title1
        self.pointAnnotation1.subtitle = "Event"
        self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from iImage? Are you sure eventPic is not nil?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating a new instance of your ViewController here `EventPageViewController()`. If this delegate method is in `EventPageViewController`, you can just call `self.eventPic.image = iImage`.

Comment: it is not the current ViewController. it is a ViewController that appears when the info button on an annotation is clicked

Comment: @Steve How is this delegate method being fired then? What is your general layout of `EventPageViewController`?

Comment: FirstViewController opens the camera when the user clicks a button. There is another line of code not included above that calls a method that does a pin. When the info button on the annotation is clicked, it opens EventPageViewController (where I want the picture to be).

Comment: All of that is also saved to cloudkit so other users can download the pins. I need each pin to have its own instance of EventPageViewController so that they each have their own different individual picture. @Pratik Patel

Comment: @Steve So you would need to pass the image back to `FirstViewController` and then pass it along w/ a segue or whatever mechanism you have to open the `EventPageViewController`.

Comment: how do i make sure that the correct image is passed to each pin, if all the pins are downloaded together at same time and I don't create an instance of EventPageViewController with each one? @Pratik Patel

Comment: @Steve, are you distinguishing between view and view controller? I agree with the comment on your question - if your **print(iImage)** returns what it does, then the issue is that something is wrong with the other end of things. Can you add ore to your question - a description of what you expect with EventViewController, why you need multiple instances of it, code/description on how you change to it's view?

Comment: I edited the question to add more code. @PratikPatel

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `eventPic` is a `UIImageView` as `IBOutlet`. So your instance of `EventPageViewController` hasn't finished loading its view and connecting outlets.

You should have a UIImage property in `EventPageViewController`.

```
class EventPageViewController {
  var eventImage: UIImage?
  @IBOutlet var eventPic:UIImageView! //you should have better name like eventImageView

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    eventPic?.image = eventImage
    ///rest goes here
  }
}
```

so from you picker delegate you can access like:

```
let eventPageViewController = EventPageViewController()
eventPageViewController.eventImage = iImage
```

Hope this helps.